Solid state devices, hole current
why do we consider hole movement as well as the electron movement in the total current term, the hole movement is the effect of the cause (electron movement), so how can they both contribute total current?

For simplicity or would the concept of negative mass be easier?

Of course one could turn the problem around and think of describing the electron motion in terms of the holes. Two things. First, the Hall experiments tell you the sign of the (majority) moving charges, and various metals under various conditions show positive charge carriers - semiconductors are not unique in this regard. Second, for semiconductors, the requirements of detailed balance on carrier concentration forces you to consider both electrons and holes on an equal basis. Semiconductor device physics will make no sense otherwise.

@JonCuster That sounds like an OK answer to me.
